# Decrease font size in KOMA-Script by 1pt

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, koma-script, scrbook

I am using the `scrbook` documentclass with the option `headings=small`. I was asked to decrease the font size of `\chapter` and `\section` by one point. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a scalable font (like `lmodern`) you can choose the fontsize with `\fontsize` and `\selectfont`. Below is a MWE. I tested how large the headings are with the `\thefontsize` macro. For me, chapter headings were 14.4pt big, so I changed it to 13.4pt and sections were 12pt so I changed it to 11pt. To change the font of special texts (like headings) KOMA-script has the command `\addtokomafont` and `\setkomafont`. With `\usekomafont` you can use the settings for the specified element.

EDIT: Added the determination of `\baselineskip` and adjusted the values in `\fontsize` to have the same relation to the new size.

```
\documentclass[headings=small]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 The font size is: \f@size pt\par Baselineskip: \the\baselineskip\par}}
\makeatother

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{13.4pt}{16.75pt}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{11pt}{12.833pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\thefontsize{\usekomafont{chapter}}
\section{test}
\thefontsize{\usekomafont{section}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works as expected. However I am a bit sceptical if it makes sense to set the same value for the font size and the baselineskip. Is there a possibility to determine the current value of the baselineskip as you did with the font size?

Comment: There is, see my edit.